# Find top parent in hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a SQL table with different project codes. A project can consist of multiple levels (sub-projects). I want to find the top level (top parent) for each of the project codes using SQL coding.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Child nvarchar(100),
    Parent nvarchar(100)

)

insert into #Temp (Child,Parent)
values
('17210',Null),
('17210-100','17210'),
('17210-100-100','17210-100'),
('1310',Null),
('1310-100','1310'),
('1310-100-100','1310-100')
;

select * from #Temp

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp
End
```

This is the result I want:

```
Child           Parent      TopParent
17210           NULL        17210
17210-100       17210       17210
17210-100-100   17210-100   17210
1310            NULL        1310
1310-100        1310        1310
1310-100-100    1310-100    1310
```

How do I find the top parent for each project number (child)? I have an idea that using recursive CTE's might be the solution, but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, that is now corrected. I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, the answer to recursive questions in SQL Server is usually a recursive cte

Comment: Have you googled recursive CTE to get hierarchy? There are many many example out there.

Comment: Also, please avoid posting images (unless the question is about UI design) as a part of the question. Use formatted text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure how it's different from any other recursive cte question, but since you've done such a great job posting sample data as DDL+DML I've decided to answer the question anyway (though it could have been just as easily closed as a duplicate).

As you wrote, using a recursive cte is the solution here:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT Child, Parent, Child As TopParent
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE Parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.Child, T.Parent, cte.TopParent
    FROM #Temp As T
    JOIN cte 
        ON T.Parent = cte.Child
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY TopParent DESC, Parent;
```

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is similar to traversing a tree using sql language. I think you might need to use stored procedures to solve this problem.
First, query all records. When traversing a record, the top parent is found through the while loop.
However, illegal data needs to be considered. For example, ('1', '2'), ('2', '3'), and ('3', '1') cause the while loop to become an infinite loop.

Comment: Really? Select all the records and then loop? Why? A recursive cte already does that for you (including the loop) in a single step.... And a stored procedure has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
CREATE TABLE Category
(
    Child nvarchar(100),
    Parent nvarchar(100)

)

insert into Category (Child,Parent)
values
('17210',Null),
('17210-100','17210'),
('17210-100-100','17210-100'),
('1310',Null),
('1310-100','1310'),
('1310-100-100','1310-100')
;

With cte (Child , Parent, LevelID, topparent)
as
(
    --Anchor
    Select Child , Parent ,0 as LevelID , Child AS TopParent
    From Category
    Where Parent is Null

    Union All

    Select c.Child , c.Parent , cte.LevelID - 1 , cte.TopParent
    From Category c inner join  cte On cte.Child=c.Parent
)

Select c.Child , c.Parent ,cte.TopParent
        From cte
```

You can use `CTE` for recursive query and find top level id for parents like above query.
this model very fast and useful.

i hope you wish the best